# I have problems to run server.js in terminal

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, terminal, localhost, port

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yznmh.png)[

```js
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
projectData = {};

// Require Express to run server and routes

const express = require('express');

const app = express();
// Start up an instance of app

const PORT = 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Hi');
    console.log(`the port that we will use is ${port}`);
});



/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
app.use(cors());
// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('website'));


// Setup Server
app.post('/link', function(req,res) {
    
});
```

[What should i do to run this in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlk6F.png)
*I tried alot  of solutions bot it's not working
in the terminal[

1.

---

### it can not find the file

][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/farfb.png)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the 'body-parser' library and send it to call in your file

> npm install body-parser

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use bodyparser if you use latest or after 4.0 version of Express.js. You can use

```
app.use(express.json()) // Parse Json Bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded()); //Parse URL-encoded bodies
```

as middlewares instead, without any package. They will solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).